# I want angular5 PDF viewer plugin to use in ionic3 application and web app

Tags: javascript, ionic3, angular5

Is there any ionic3/angular5 PDF reader plugin with below feature :

- Pinch zoom
- No file size limitation
- Search feature
- cross platform (android, IOS, Web App)

NOTE : I have already used following packages :

1) https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer (doesn't allow pinch zoom)

2) https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdfjs-viewer (doesn't allow pinch zoom)

3) google doc viewer (Doesn't allow to display more than 25 MB file)

Thanks!

Comment: Off-topic. Describe the issue and everything you already tried (don't forget to include a copy-pastable repro of what you have that doesn't work). Specify why what you tried doesn't fulfill your needs (there might be a way around that).

Comment: yeh!! description update.

Comment: @Wasim There is a property called [useOnlyCssZoom] in ng2-pdfjs-viewer. Did you try that?